# Injecting background url("MyImageHere.png") in my SASS code with Typescript

Tags: css, typescript, sass, ionic2

I am trying to inject an image into my SASS code, using Typescript. I have gotten it to work, but it doesn't look the way it does when I use just SASS.

This is my original sass code:

```
{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background: url(../../assets/img/advance-card-tmntr.jpg) no-repeat 
    center center/cover;
    opacity: 0.5;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  }
```

And this is what it looks like, which is ultimately the end goal.

[image]

Now I am trying to take this line:

```
background: url(../../assets/img/advance-card-tmntr.jpg) no-repeat
```

and replace it with a unique image URL from my typescript file, such as user?.avatar.

I got the image to display using:

```
[style.background]="'url(' + user.avatar + ')'"
```

But I cannot get the image to display correctly. This is what it looks like with my "hacky-code":

[image]

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: In TypeScript/JavaScript you should only set `style.backgroundImage='url({${user.avatar})'` and not the "shorthand" background. If you do so the other background styles are inherited from your stylesheet. (also, you'll need more than css to turn that girl into Schwarzenegger(?))

Comment: Good catch about the Arnold photo, but I was just trying to use a simple example that I had in my project folder, and the image of the girl is the dynamic photo that i'm trying to inject.

As for the code that you linked, how would I go about including the "no-repeat center center/cover;" part?

Comment: When I use the style.backgroundImage='url({${user.avatar})', it gives me the same output that I had before, with the repeating photo, and without the blue overlay (not pictured in my above css, but I can include it if necessary).

Comment: You still need the css file included and in the css file need to set `background-position: center; background-size:cover;`

Comment: The image of the girl is repeating, is what I mean.

Comment: Maybe the following pen is enough for you to work with and figure out what you should change? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QajpKg 
I'm afraid you're not giving enough to give an actual direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `background-image` instead of `background`.
example:

HTML file

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="bg" [style.background-image]="'url('+avatar+')'">    
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS file

```
.bg {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

TS file

```
avatar = "http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/smile-256x256.png";
```